# How to change attribute to excel line shape converting vba script in win32com

Tags: excel, python-3.x, vba, win32com

I would like to convert a `VBA` script in `win32com` code in order to select and modify property of line shape in excel worksheet.
I am able to select the line (I see the line selected in excel worksheet) but I'm not able to change the property.

Could someone help me?

VBA Code

```vb
Sheets("Maps").Select
Sheets("Maps").Shapes.Range(Array(item_in_review_2)).Select

With Selection.ShapeRange.Line
    .Weight = 3
    If .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0) Then
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 255, 0)
    Else
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    End If
End With
```

This is my code in python

```
import win32com.client as win32
import os

def rgbToInt(rgb):
    colorInt = rgb[0] + (rgb[1] * 256) + (rgb[2] * 256 * 256)
    return colorInt

xlApp = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
xlApp.Visible = True

wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open('C:\\Users\\xxx\\PycharmProjects\\prova\\Book1.xlsx')
sht = wb.Worksheets('Maps')

OTS_review = 'test'

changeline = sht.Shapes(OTS_review).Select()

changeline.Width = 3

if changeline.ForeColor.RGB == rgbToInt((255,0,0)):
    changeline.ForeColor.RGB = rgbToInt((0, 255, 0))
else:
    changeline.ForeColor.RGB = rgbToInt((255, 0, 0))
```

This is error reported

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:/Users/xxxx/PycharmProjects/prova/xxx.py", line 18, in  changeline.Width = 3
>
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'Width'

Comment: Not sure but shouldn't `changeline = sht.Shapes(OTS_review).Select()` be without `.Select()`?

Comment: If I remove .Select() the Error doesn't appear but following the code changeline.Width = 3 nothing happen.
Morover I get the error <object has no attribute 'ForeColor'>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try maybe change to this:

```
changeline = sht.Shapes(OTS_review)  # or maybe with .Select()
changeline.ShapeRange.Line.Width = 3
changeline.ShapeRange.Line.ForeColor.RGB = rgbToInt((0, 255, 0))
```

'or

```
changeline = sht.Shapes(OTS_review)
changeline.Line.Width = 3
changeline.Line.ForeColor.RGB = rgbToInt((0, 255, 0))
```

I resolve by changing Width and Weight

```
changeline = sht.Shapes(OTS_review)
changeline.Line.Weight = 3
changeline.Line.ForeColor.RGB = rgbToInt((0, 255, 0))
```

Comment: With .Select() return 
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'ShapeRange'
Without .Select() return
AttributeError: '<win32com.gen_py.Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library.Shape instance at 0x104825520>' object has no attribute 'ShapeRange'

on line changeline.ShapeRange.Line.Width = 3

Comment: I've added new lines to my above answer